# Synonym for "motion"

Tags: synonyms

What is an uncommon synonym for the noun "motion" (movement)? I'm looking for cool sounding words like "twitter" that are synonyms or somehow relate to motion, the noun that means movement. Example: "I bought a motion detector to alert my household of criminals."

Comment: Why do you have a household of criminals?? :O

Comment: Have you tried consulting a thesaurus?

Comment: @Barmar I didn't find anything good

Answer (score 0):

Some possibilities are:

*Flux* - continuous change, passage, or movement ([source](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/flux))

*Sway* - the act of swaying; swaying movement ([source](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sway))

*Motility* - the capability to move spontaneously, a term from biology ([source](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/motility))

Answer (score 0):

Merriam-Webster says about 'flicker' -  to appear or pass briefly or quickly.  Detecting a flicker could be used for 'motion detector'.  Btw, Flickr is a popular image hosting site.

Answer (score 0):

**Disturbance** and **commotion** can be used to describe activity or motion that is not normal (an outbreak of disorder).

**Flutter** can mean to go with irregular or aimless motion.

**Quiver** and **tremble** is a slight but rapid repetitive motion. A **spasm** might be a slight non-repeating motion.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a cool, uncommon word like twitter then how about **kinemat**, motion in classical Greek. From which we have the English word [Kinematics](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kinematics); a branch of dynamics that deals with aspects of motion apart from considerations of mass and force ( merriam-webster.com ).

You may also want to consider:
[kinetic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/kinetic), (adjective)
1.
pertaining to motion.
2.
caused by motion.
3.
characterized by movement: